# Replace GUID in web.config during publish

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, web-config-transform

I'm looking for a way to have a GUID in my web.config file, which gets transformed into a new GUID at publish-time.

For example:

```
<add key="someGuid" value="aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa" />
```

and when you publish the app using MSBuild or Visual Studio's publish screen, the resulting config file, after transformation, contains a brand-new GUID, like:

```
<add key="someGuid" value="ab15c61ba16d1651a6c89a621d64c4f8" />
```

Basically, I need a new GUID every time I publish the app, but also need the ability to replace this GUID on demand without a full recompile.

Before I build something custom, using a placeholder and replacing the text manually, I wanted to see if there's a config transform or built-in MSBuild function that could help.

Comment: Have you found a way to do it with xdt transforms in web.config.release?

Comment: @Rumpelstinsk I ended up with something custom outside of web.config which actually worked better anyway. I don't know if there's a built-in way, and since this question was asked, they've done a ton of work with the framework, so I don't know if there's a simple built-in way, aside from the listed answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MSBuild, you can create a new GUID like this

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SomeGuid>$([System.Guid]::NewGuid())</SomeGuid>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And then you can use the XmlPoke task to make the replacement using your newly created property $(SomeGuid).

Excerpted from in the book [MSBuild Trickery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/061550907X) tricks #9 and #101

Comment: For those of us, who haven´t purchased your book, could you please provide an example of how to make it work using the `XmlPoke` task without altering the `web.config` file to be transformed?